# What characters to escape in string to XML in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing

I need to work with XML which is represented as string and then to convert it as XML in SQL Server 2012. I have problem with query string parameters (I have URLs inside that text with contains query string parameters with &).

I see that there are 5 symbols that have to be escaped (and require escape in different sections in the XML ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents)).

I can use `SELECT @Input FOR XML PATH('')` or `SELECT CAST(CAST('<root><![CDATA[' + @Input + ']]></root>' AS XML) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`, but I noticed that `'` and `"` are not escaped. It is strange that `CDATA` escapes `&, <, >`.

I can also can use:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@Input,'&', '&amp;')
                ,'<', '&lt;')
            ,'>', '&gt;')
        ,'"', '&quot;')
    ,'''', '&apos;')
```

which will escape all, but I like first solution - more neat and clean one.

So my question: which characters are proper to escape?

Comment: Don't use interpolation for database queries; use parameterized queries (because interpolation is likely to lead to SQL injection attacks). Then you won't have to escape anything.

Comment: The data just contains URLs. That data is not used in URLs. Thanks for remark anyway, @K.Matthews

Comment: ah, reading comprehension failure on my part. :)

Comment: Add some source values and the expected output.